# Weird error when trying to change worksheet name in c#

Tags: c#, excel, com

Here is the code throwing the error:

```
string[] sheetNames = new string[] {"Raw"};

for (int s = 1; s <= sheetNames.Count(); s++)
{
    Excel.Worksheet newSheet = new Excel.Worksheet();
    newSheet.Name = sheetNames[s];
    newWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(newSheet);
}
```

I am getting an `Unable to cast COM object of type 'WorksheetClass' to interface type '_Worksheeet'` exception. I have no idea what that means.

Appreciate all help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you create the `Worksheet` object is the problem. You need to define an `Application` object first and than call something like: `Application.WorkSheets.Add()`
Example:

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlApp.Visible = true;
Excel.Workbook xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add() as Excel.Workbook;
Excel.Worksheet xlSheet = xlWb.Sheets[1] as Excel.Worksheet;
```